# How to Avoid the plugin JS file which is Conflict to all the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ninja-forms

I am working with WordPress and I am using the **ultimate-product-catalogue(Product Catalog)** **Plugin**. Actually the Problem is this plugin  giving the Error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slider is not a function(…)
```

But plugin functionality is working properly But I also used the other Plugin **Ninja form** **Plugin** its functionality is not working Means form Which I
 created is not showing.

How to resolved this type of problem. Please share any Idea or trick.

Comment: Have you found the file names which is conflicting between those two plugins ?

Comment: yes I use noconflict functionality but another file creating issue

Comment: Find the culprit file first.

Comment: I found and using var jQ3 = jQuery.noConflict() in culprit  file but another file giving issue

Comment: Which file and where it has been enqueued ? Give the full details.

Comment: https://manresa-sj.com/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-product-catalogue/js/upcp-jquery-functions.js?ver=4.6.1 and it is showing on the header

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127257/discussion-between-shahzad-ditro-and-the-dramatist).